# how to insert variables into src (source) with javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, src

i have a video from videojs:

```
<video id="movie" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
                preload="auto" width="638" height="480" poster="resources/movies/botschafter/1/test/skins/express_show_silver/video_titel.png"
                data-setup="{}">
                <source src="resources/botschafter/module1/1/test/botschafter_herkunft.flv" type='video/mp4' />
                <source src="my_video.webm" type='video/webm' />
            </video>
```

i want to build source dynamically. now it is static: `<source src="resources/botschafter/module1/1/test/botschafter_herkunft.flv" type='video/mp4' />`

i like to have it like this:

var **moduleName**;
var **stepNr**;

`<source src="resources/botschafter/"+ moduleName +"/"+ stepNr +"/test/botschafter_herkunft.flv" type='video/mp4' />`

just because src already surrounded with "", how to insert new variables into it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
var code = '<source src="resources/botschafter/' + moduleName +'/'+ stepNr + '/test/botschafter_herkunft.flv" type="video/mp4" />'
```

You can use double quotes inside single quotes: `'he said: "I love you!"'` and backwards: `"he said: 'I love you!'"`. Also, you may screen symbols inside strings: `"Here's some \"quoted\" text"`

Comment: hi, i tried it like this & its not running.  <source src='resources/movies/"+ moduleName +"/"+ stepNr +"/test/botschafter_herkunft.flv' type='video/mp4' />